# I can't get my program to write a java file into html

Tags: java, html

I have to write a program where the user selects a .java file and the program creates an html file and writes all of the code into it, adding the necessary HTML tags so it will display properly. No matter what I think of and find online I can't get anything to properly make this happen, the only thing that writes is those HTML tags that are in the string I created.

It runs, user can select the file and choose where to save it. The file itself gets created, but none of the information from the .java file gets into the .html file.

```
package convertjavahtml;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptingFunctions.readLine;

public class ConvertJavaHTML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String name = null;
        String newname = null;
        try {
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Java", "java");
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                name = file.getName();
                newname = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("."));
            }

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("html files (*.html)", "html");
            JFileChooser saver = new JFileChooser();
            saver.setFileFilter(filter2);
            saver.setSelectedFile(new File(newname));
            int returnVal2; 
            returnVal2 = saver.showSaveDialog(null);
            int response = 0;

            if(returnVal2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {                
                FileWriter write = new FileWriter(saver.getSelectedFile()+".html");
                write.close();
            }

            File file = new File(name);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            String beg = "<h2>Demo.java</h2>\n<html>\n<pre>\n<body>\n";
            String end = "\n</body>\n</pre>\n</html>"; 
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(newname + ".html"));
            out.println(beg);

            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getName(file)))) {

            String readLine;
            while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(newname), "utf-8"))) {
                    writer.write(readLine);
                }
            }

            }

            out.print(end);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

    }

private static char handleFile(File file, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    try
        (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);

        Reader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader)){
        return handleChars(buffer);
    }
}

private static char handleChars(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    int r;
    while((r = reader.read()) != -1)
    {
        char ch = (char) r;
        System.out.println(ch + " ");
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: This code will not compile, would you fix this? Ex: the final `try` statement is missing a `{` and has an extra `(`

Comment: You'll need to escape the code - it may contain characters that have special meaning in html (`<`, `&` etc.)

Comment: When asking a question in the future, it helps to explain exactly what you have done, what the code is doing, what it should be doing, and provide any outputs/error messages you receive.

Comment: I can’t decide which is worse:  outputting an `<h2>` before you start your `<html>`, or outputting the `<body>` inside a `<pre>` section.   Learn the proper HTML document structure, and/or pass the result to an HTML validator study the errors then go back and fix the structure.